# Expression error in combining optional parameter

Tags: c#

When i click the print button am getting expression error
Here, I am passing three parameter namely printername, printertray, no.of copies. Out of these three the printer tray is optional. Because the tray selection is not mandatory in all the cases.

```
public bool Print(string printerName, string printerTray=null,int? copies=1) {
if(copies == null || copies < 1) return false;        

if (printerName.IsDefined() && printerTray.IsDefined()) {
                    project.Regions[0].Device.Name = "\" " + "\

"".Combine(printerName, printerTray)  +"\" ";
}
```

I am getting an expression error when I try to combine the parameter.
Can anyone help me am new to this .net

Comment: What is `IsDefined()`?

Comment: printer value and tray value are defined

Comment: C# does not have methods in the framework like `IsDefined` or `Combine` on strings. We cannot help you, if we don't know what your custom functions do. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: sorry for the trouble.As you said the "combine" & "Isdefined" are custom function  .  public static string CombineIfAllDefined(String separator, params string[] strings) {
            if (strings.Any(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)) {
                return null;
            }

            return Combine(" ", strings);
        }

Comment: they have created custom control for combining the optional parameters

Comment: public static string Combine(this String separator, params string[] strings) {
            string combined = null;

            foreach (var current in strings) {
                if (combined.IsDefined() && current.IsDefined()) {
                    combined += separator;
                }

                combined += current;
            }

            return combined;
        }

Comment: Ok, your code has an error that I cannot tell whether it is actually your problem or just a bad copy and paste job here. Can you please format your code? Brackets are missing, there is a linebreak that seems random and your quotation marks don't add up. Maybe that is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is your code, properly formatted and without compiler errors:

```
public bool Print(string printerName, string printerTray = null, int? copies = 1) 
{
    if(copies == null || copies < 1)
    {
        return false;        
    }

    if (printerName.IsDefined() && printerTray.IsDefined()) 
    {
        project.Regions[0].Device.Name = "\" "
                                       + "".Combine(printerName, printerTray)  
                                       + "\" ";
    }
}
```